# How to echo the date and time in gitlab job output?

Tags: gitlab

I'd like to output the date and time at certain points of the job. This seems to produce a syntax error:

```yaml
before_script:
- echo "before_script: %DATE% %TIME%"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you listed is for Windows. If your GitLab runner uses Linux, then you need to use POSIX commands.

You can also use the predefined variable `CI_JOB_STARTED_AT` for the start time.

```yaml
before_script:
  - 'echo "Job start: $CI_JOB_STARTED_AT"'
script:
  - 'echo "Script start: $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")"'
```

Comment: Ok, just added this and it said that my yaml file was invalid `echo "DEPOLY STAGE COMPLETE: $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")"` - `jobs:deploy:script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep`(?)

Comment: Please don't call this "Linux commands". The kernel has pretty much nothing to do with it, it just provides some POSIX-like API.

Comment: @JoeTidee The problem was with the colon in the echo command, which is not compatible with YAML standards. You have to wrap the entire command in single quotes. I've updated my answer to reflect this and tested it out in GitLab.